# One to One Relationship with Different Primary Key in EF 6.1 Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I am having an issue getting a reference to the employee object from the PayGroup object using Entity Framework 6.1. I have a foreign key in the database on PayGroup.SupervisorId -> Employee.EmployeeId. Note that this is a zero or one-to-one relationship (a pay group can only have one supervisor and an employee can only be the supervisor of one pay group).

According to [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/159), it is not possible to have a foreign key on a table with a different primary key. I've added the foreign key to the database manually but I can't figure out how to set up the fluent api mapping to be able to get the employee object from pay group.

**Pay Group Table**

[image: Pay Group Table]

**Employee Table**

[image: Employee Table]

*Note: There is a foreign key from PayGroup.SupervisorId - Employee.EmployeeId in the database.*

Below are the DTO's (I don't currently have any working relationship mapping between these classes):

```
public class PayGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Supervisor { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You try something like [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`one-to-one` relationship with explicit FK property (like your `PayGroup.SupervisorId`) is not supported.

So remove that property from the model:

```
public class PayGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Supervisor { get; set; }
}
```

and use the following fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PayGroup>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Supervisor)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("SupervisorId"));
```

The `WithOptional()` call specifies two things. First that there is no inverse navigation property in `Employee` class, and second that the FK is optional (`Allow Nulls = true` in the table).

If you decide to add inverse navigation property

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual PayGroup PayGroup { get; set; } // <=
}
```

change it to `WithOptional(e => e.PayGroup)`.

If you want to make it required (`Allow Nulls = false` in the table), then use the corresponding `WithRequiredDependent` overload (*Dependent* here means that the `Employee` will be the *principal* and `PayGroup` will be the *dependent*).

Comment: So simple when it's explained clearly. I think I was getting messed up by the WithOptional and HasRequired. I also was doing my best to not remove the SupervisorId field from PayGroup. Thanks!

Comment: well, this works to some degree. if in the **Pay Group Table** the "SupervisorId" is NULL in the db, then when I do a query with link, I get an error saying that the null value can not be converted to a non-nullable type.